# cannot set tr height to 100% or TD width to 100%

Tags: html, css

According to the inspect elements menu, this thing called `<tbody>` exists, and `<tr>` is inside it. The problem is, `tbody`, is 100% height and width, which it should be, but `<tr>` is always 4 pixels less in height than it should be, even when styled at 100% height

THEN

inside there are two `td`s, one has 20% and one has 80% width, but they both have these annoying border type things, that i cant get rid of, it looks like margin but honestly cannot find anything

This question is a bit of a mess, but i cant find any sort of solution

Comment: Tables smells like the 90’s. Why won’t you use css?

Comment: @emix What if OP needs just that - a simple table?

Comment: @emix Nothing wrong with tables.

Comment: Can you include your HTML?

Comment: One can create amazingly simply table with flex / display table.

Comment: Please include a [mre] of the HTML and CSS you are using. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it runnable here.

Comment: @emix The `table` element is recommended for use when displaying tabular data. It has all of the appropriate accessibility features already built in, the element names describe what they contain reasonably well (as opposed to a bunch of nested `div`s). There are many, many reasons to use the `table` element for its intended purpose.

Comment: - **A**bout tables, sometimes it can be usefull just  to drop a link to remind how & why to use them, they do are usefull for their purpose. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics - **A**bout styling, there is also plenty ressource avalaible : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Styling_tables . A little search would answer most basic question.

Comment: for a single row, you do not set height to td but to table. (tr is also a wrapper not meant be seen but to hold datas together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the padding around "tr". A great tool to use is Pesticide (it's a Google Chrome extension) that when it turns on, it will show the outlines of different sections to help you determine what is being controlled in terms of padding/margin. It sounds like there may be a padding issue. If you turn on Chrome Developer, under the Element tab on the right side, if you scroll all the way down, you can see the box model and see the padding/margin that is used in the respective section.

Comment: border-spacing, border-collapse,box-sizing if borders or padding is involved are also hints, but the op does not give a clue about what he really  did.